# How to store a binary number in a C long int?

Tags: c

I want to use a `long` `int` to store a binary number. I am aware of how to put it in an `array` but was wondering if there was a way to use a `long` `int` to take input of a binary number without adding any extensions to `gcc` compiler.

```
long long int test_binary = 00010011101;
printf("Test Binary: %lli",test_binary);
```

prints garbage value even when the number doesn't start/end with zeroes.

Comment: @BoPersson sorry, I edited and added more to my question. I am trying to store/work with in the code and print the binary number in its binary format.

Comment: There is no support in Standard C for binary constants (that is, there's no `0b00010011101` analogous to `0x9d`), and there's no `printf` format for binary, either (there's `%x`, but not `%b`).  If you had your heart set on it, you could do `test_binary = strtoll("00010011101", NULL, 2)`.

Comment: Values starting with a `0` are considered to be octal (base 8). There really isn't a standard way to use binary literals,  but your compiler *might* anyway allow you to write `0b00010011101` for binary data.

Comment: @BoPersson Indeed, I just tried, and `0b00010011101` works fine, and `0b00010011101L` does, too.

Comment: @BoPersson `test_binary` won't be a literal in this program, it will be user inputted and I would have to work with that number also within my code. But I see, I will ask my professor to see if I can use arrays. thank you.

Comment: If the user is inputting the number, read it in as a string, and convert it to an `int` using `strtol` or `strtoll`.

Comment: @SteveSummit I have a difficult professor, but I hope so too haha, thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that C++14 has support for binary constants using `0b1101'1001'0011'1100` notation (where the use of apostrophes for grouping is optional).  Oddly, I can find nothing indicating support for binary integer representation in I/O operations — in C++14 or C++17 drafts.  I don't know whether that's an oversight or intentional (or I'm looking in the wrong place).  I'm not aware of plans to include binary constants in C — or the punctuation characters.  They complicate naïve lexical analyzers (and don't even think of asking about C++ raw string literals!).